# If/else variable assigned before if statement executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, flask, flask-wtforms

The first instance of the `number_of_discs` receives data from another page and this value is visible in the form.

```
#####Results Page

@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
        form = SendForm()

        number_of_discs = request.args.get('number_of_discs', '')
```

In the below code, If the function `form.validate_on_submit()` returns `False`, I want the `number_of_discs` variable to be reassigned the value that has been typed into the form to amended the original data.

```
#####Results Page

@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
        form = SendForm()

        number_of_discs = request.args.get('number_of_discs', '')

        if form.validate_on_submit():
                        try:
                                models.insert(form)
                        except:
                                print ("hasn't worked")
                        else:
                                return redirect(url_for('success'))
        else:
                        number_of_discs = form.number_of_discs.data


        return render_template(
        'results.html', title='Results', number_of_discs=number_of_discs, form=form

    )
```

It works to an extent in that the variable is reassigned whatever is typed into the form. However, my problem now is that when I first load the page, the `number_of_discs` variable in the `else` statement seems to be initialized as the default value, rather than the first declaration of the `number_of_discs` variable (i.e. the data from the other page). So to summarize, the variable in the `if`/`else` statement seems to precede the variable assigned before/outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid overwriting that default value by 
executing the current `if/else` only when the request is `'POST'`:

```
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
   ...
   number_of_discs = request.args.get('number_of_discs', '')
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if form.validate_on_submit():
         ...
      else:
         ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I'm getting     if request.method = 'POST':
                      
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   with an arrow pointing at the equals sign.

Comment: @bms9nmh Ouch! Typo fixed.

Comment: You my friend could part the sea.